# ASP.Net data binding to label control with text

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

How to add text to label with bound data?

```
Text='<%# Bind("DeliveryPrice") %>'
```

Trying to display **£** 1.23. Tried numerous examples posted to forums and no luck:

```
Text='<%# "£: " +Eval("DeliveryPrice").ToString() %>'
Text='<%# String.Format("£: {0}", Bind("DeliveryPrice")) %>'
Text="£" + '<%# Bind("DeliveryPrice") %>'
Text="£" & '<%# Bind("DeliveryPrice") %>'
Text='£ <%# DataBinder.Bind(Container.DataItem,"DeliveryPrice") %>'
Text='<%# "£" & Bind("DeliveryPrice") %>'
Text='<%# "£" + Bind("DeliveryPrice") %>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Eval` function has an overload that takes a formatting string:

```
Text='<%# Eval("DeliveryPrice", "£: {0}") %>'
```